# alogrithm with two integers

Tags: algorithm, integer

Suppose we have A and B, both integers, Is there a alogrithm that generate this?

1. some operates with A that resulted C
2. some operates with B that resulted D
3. some operates with A and B that resulted E
4. C equals D equals E

Comment: Huh?  How about `def algorithm(x) { return 1; }`?

Comment: don;t want a constant, -_-

Comment: A constant is the only solution to the problem you've posed.

Comment: For reasons that really should be immediately obvious but I'll explain them in my answer anyway.

Comment: This sounds like an abstract logic question rather than a programing question. It is badly formed/written so it's hard to make out an actual question. Could you rewrite `1. Some function f, such that f(a) = c` etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. `C(A) = D(B) = E(A,B) = 0` meets all your requirements.

It's immediately obvious that all three functions must return the same constant. Since `C` must equal `D`, and `D` does not vary with `A`, `C` cannot vary with `A` either. Since `C` is only a function of `A` and cannot vary with `A`, it must be a constant. Since the other functions must equal `C` and `C` is constant, they must also be constant.

Comment: @KunChe See my update. It's trivial to prove it must be a constant.